# Implementing a unique primary key for distributed databases

Tags: distributed-databases

I've got an issue to find a way to create a global primary key to a given relation (namely "Patient")

In a distributed database there are three local sub-systems: surgery department, emergency department and some other department. In each department, the "Patient" table has a local primary key that is different to the others sub-systems.

I read about global and local indexing in distributed DB. Can it give a solution to that? Or is there any other technique to solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The answer may be platform-specific, so you may want to mention the database you're working with. Some DBMSes offer built-in GUID generators.